# System Settings wont open after driver update

Tags: drivers, nvidia, steam

I just wanna say first off I'm not a very advanced user but I had some framerate issues and so a few minutes ago I updated to the new Nvidia 375 driver using a ppa and it told me that it is successful and it even shows it in the additional drivers now.
Only thing is that Steam, and system settings will not open anymore. Should I wait or should I restart? What can I do? Thanks in advance.

edit:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM206 [GeForce GTX 960] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GM206 [GeForce GTX 960]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command. Did you reboot after you installed the driver.

Comment: I did not reboot yet. Waiting for answer. I have edited the question with the results. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can always remove this driver and install the old one.

Comment: So should I not try rebooting? past experiences led to crashing the system, but it was only because of insufficient disk space and I have enough of that now.

Comment: I do not think rebooting can change anything, but you can always try.

Comment: That is interesting. I restarted and it works fine now. Steam launches and System Settings is fine as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the driver that does not work well for some reason by

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-367
```

Reboot.

Comment: I'll vote it as best and if you want you can edit it to include rebooting ^^

Comment: It is very obvious )))